# Node-Express MySQL API Outputing JSON Array as String

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, json, api

Trying to setup an Express API server to grab some data for a portfolio site. I have set up the MySQL table with an JSON data type for my 'images' column. 'images' is supposed to have multiple image links for a gallery. However, the server outputs the images array as a string instead of an array of strings.

**Javascript Code on the API Server**

```js
app.get("/getWorks", (req, res) => {
  let sql = "select * from works";
  db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    res.send(result);
  });
});
```

**The Results**

```json
[
  {
    "workID": 1,
    "title": "example",
    "images": "[\"https://SERVER_IP/images/example.png\", \"https://SERVER_IP/images/example.png\"]"
  }
]
```

**Workaround**

I found out a work around to get the desired output adding this:

```js
result = result.map((row) => ((row.images = JSON.parse(row.images)), row));
```

```json
[
  {
    "workID": 1,
    "title": "example",
    "images": ["https://SERVER_IP/images/example.png", "https://SERVER_IP/images/example.png"]
  }
]
```

How come the query is not outputting the data in a JSON array in the first place even though I specified that particular column to be JSON data type in the table?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out the problem. I was using the wrong MySQL node package. Need MySQL2 for the json formatting.

```
npm install mysql2
```

```js
const mysql = require("mysql2");
```